# perspective: 1000px; not work in IE10

Tags: css

I deleted all code that isn't necessary to solve this problem, like the prefix -WEBKIT-, -MOZ- ,the characteristics, and the other faces of the cube . I know that there are already other post with the same question, but in anyone of this there is the solution, so I would to understand why this propriety doesn't work on IE10.

```
.container-cube {
 perspective: 1000px;
 -ms-perspective: 1000px;
}
#cube {
 transform-style: preserve-3d;
 -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
 transform: translateZ( -100px );
 -ms-transform: translateZ( -100px );
 transition: all ease 2s;
 -ms-transition: all ease 2s;
}


#cube .front{
  transform: rotateY( 0deg ) 
  translateZ( 150px ); -ms-transform:        
  rotateY(0deg ) translateZ(150px );  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is likely not `perspective: 1000px;`, it's probably that `transform-style: preserve-3d`, is [unsupported in IE10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673529%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#the_ms_transform_style_property).

Answer (score 0):

"I found the solution at this problem in this site:"[codepen.io/jonathan/pen/xiJLn]

"You have to give a movement at all faces of the cube, is not the same of mine but is always good, if you want make a different movement you have to change the CSS or , like in my case, use Java Script".

Thanks for help.